# Opening a dynamically populated jqm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

While I'm a bit of a dab hand in php, I'm stumbling my way through a JQuery Mobile project via Phonegap for an iOS app.  So getting my head around javascript (quickly) has been challenging.  Managed to solve most problems mostly with the help of the good folk here, so thought I'd ask this one which I can't find a solution for.

I have a list which is generated from an ajax request (summary with a heading and short description), with the full detail being stored in an SQLite DB for offline use.  I'm wanting to open a dialog with the full detail on click.  JQM's data-rel dialog is a breeze for static pages, but I can't figure a means to send the dialog page an index parameter to pull the data from the DB.  Once I get the parameter down to the "page" I'm pretty confident pulling the data and replacing the DOM elements, so the short question is how do I send the index parameter from the list to the dialog page?

Thanks heaps in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in your list (I am assuming `data-role="listview"` here), build the links that represent clickable elements:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="dialog.html?id=someId" data-rel="dialog">Show details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where you insert `someId` dynamically when you create your list.

In dialog page you parse your URL and get the ID.

**Update**

The following confirmed as working in Safari (on my desktop):

```
<a href="dialog.html?id=someId" data-rel="dialog">Show details</a>
```

and the usage would be:

```
$.mobile.path.parseUrl($(this).data('url')).search
```

which would contain the following string:

```
?id=someId
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but in Safari it doesn't send the parameter.  the url is composite.html#accolades&ui-state=dialog where composite.html is the whole page and accolades is the page with the list view calling the dialog. So, there's no parameter to get. Dialog comes up as it should, but the divs are empty.

Comment: That's odd, sorry though - I will be able to test it tomorrow. I'll try to get back to you.

Comment: Thanks ZenMaster, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks ZenMaster, that did it.  For any other noobs that come across this, it returns the whole thing, i.e. '?id=someId', not just 'someId'.  I needed an integer so used finalid = parseInt(id.slice(id.indexOf('=')+1));  Thanks again.